# Using OFL SIL font to logo

Tags: copyright, licensing, patents, human-rights, commerce

I have a question. I download FontAwesome (SIL OFL licence 1.1). I took icon- bulb and expand it to curves in vector software. I edit that icon that the icon never look like original anymore. And I add part of another icon to that bulb. Can I use it for comemrcial logo for my client? I just used that original icon and change it a lot, just because I need taht shape of bulb.

Comment: Have you read [the basics](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/i-have-a-question-about-copyright-what-should-i-read-before-i-ask-it)? Have you read the license itself? This seems obviously outside the terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [related but distinct question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/19896/sil-ofl-license-v1-1-and-embedding-icon-fonts-in-software-binaries). Under SIL's license, you cannot use their font names in a derived product (make up your own name), and you cannot sell their fonts alone (you can sell a product that includes the font); any derivative has to be made available under the same license.

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining
>   a copy of the Font Software, to use, study, copy, merge, embed,
>   modify, redistribute, and sell modified and unmodified copies of the
>   Font Software

Creating a graphic object based on their font and using it for commercial purposes is covered by their permissions.